# How to declare a duration variable in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using the Saxon library to apply some XSLT 2.0 transformations.

I'm trying to add some code that will print all the dates between two given dates.

To that end, I'm trying to figure out to work with duration variables.  Specifically, I want to take the first date, add one day to it, print it, and then repeat until the first date has been increased all the way up to the second date.

I've written the following in my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template name="get_rundatesNode">
    <xsl:param name="startDate" />
    <xsl:param name="endDate" />
    <xsl:variable name="oneDay" select='xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D")' />

  </xsl:template>
```

I see the following errors from Saxon:

> Error at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[2]/xsl:variable[1]   XPST0081
>   XPath syntax error at char 0 on line -1 in {xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D"}
>   :
>       Undeclared namespace prefix {xs} Warning: at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[2]/xsl:variable[1]   SXWN9001: A variable
>   with no following sibling instructions has no effect

I think I'm probably using the wrong syntax and I'm totally confused by the documentation.  I can't find an example of this being done correctly.  Please let me know how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a declaration at the top of your stylesheet that binds the `xs` prefix to the W3C schema  namespace, probably also with a directive to prune the copying of namespaces to the result tree:

```
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
```

The warning is just telling you that you haven't finished adding code yet to your template and so the variable isn't going to do anything for you.

Comment: One other point: the fact that the errors are located using paths rather than line numbers suggests you are supplying the stylesheet as a tree rather than as a file: is there any particular reason you are doing that? Line numbers make it easier to identify and fix the error.

Comment: The stylesheet is coming from a string variable that is ultimately read from a SQL database.